# Can i Add Two Tab Bars in same View controller one tab bar at bottom and one tab bar at top

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, xcode10, swift4.2

I am developing an app in swift 4 and i want to add two tab bars at same time one at bottom and other at top. i have added bottom tab bar but have no idea how to add second tab bar in the same controller

thanks

Comment: Why don't you give it a try yourself and state your issues here if you face any.

Comment: @iPeter thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do. Add on `UITabBar` at bottom and another at top like shown below.

However, you can select one item in each `UITabBar` once. For example, if you selected `Contacts` in top tabbar, you can also select `Favourites` at the bottom tabbar as well. If you want to select one item in both tabbars you should program manually.

Add the code to `viewDidLoad`:

```
let tabbar1 = UITabBar() //Note that tabbar height is fixed to 49
view.addSubview(tabbar1)

tabbar1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tabbar1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

let contacts = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.contacts, tag: 100)
let bookmarks = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.bookmarks, tag: 101)
tabbar1.setItems([contacts, bookmarks], animated: false)

let tabbar2 = UITabBar() //Note that tabbar height is fixed to 49
view.addSubview(tabbar2)

tabbar2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tabbar2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
tabbar2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

let downloads = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.downloads, tag: 103)
let favorites = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarItem.SystemItem.favorites, tag: 104)
tabbar2.setItems([downloads, favorites], animated: false)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer but i am not using story board, can you guid me through programming that would be helpful.

Comment: what if i want to add View Controllers to these tab bars items?